# Angular ngMaterial Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

[image]

I cannot inject ngMaterial into my app. I have loaded ngAria and angular.js before angular-material. Here is my routes.js and index.html. Does something look wrong?

---

routes.js

```
'use strict';
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial','appRoutes', 'appControllers', 'appServices', 'appDirectives', 'appFilters']);
 var appRoutes = angular.module('appRoutes', []);
 var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);
 var appServices = angular.module('appServices', []);
 var appDirectives = angular.module('appDirectives', []);
 var appFilters = angular.module('appFilters', []);

 app.constant('Options', {baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4001'});
```

---

index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.css">
...
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use the non-minified angular.js for more clearer errors

Comment: Thanks. Just found the error, forgot to add angular-animate before angular-material.